# What is the difference between table level operation and record-level operation?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

While going through the documentation of django to muster the detailed knowledge, i endured the word 'table level operation' and 'record level operation'. What is the difference in between them? Could anyone please explain me this 2 word with example? Does they have other name too?

P.S I am not asking their difference just because i feel they are alike but i feel it can be more clear to comprehend this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the context of Django, record level operations are those that on a single records. An example is when you define custom methods in a model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()

    def baby_boomer_status(self):
        "Returns the person's baby-boomer status."
        import datetime
        if self.birth_date < datetime.date(1945, 8, 1):
            return "Pre-boomer"
        elif self.birth_date < datetime.date(1965, 1, 1):
            return "Baby boomer"
        else:
            return "Post-boomer"
```

Table level operations are those that act on a set of records and an example of these are when you define a ModelManager for a class:

```
# First, define the Manager subclass.
class DahlBookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(DahlBookManager, self).get_queryset().filter(author='Roald Dahl')

# Then hook it into the Book model explicitly.
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    dahl_objects = DahlBookManager() # The Dahl-specific manager.
```

PS: I took these examples from django documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know specifically how Django people use the terms, but 'record-level operation' should mean an operation on 1 or more records while a 'table-level operation' should mean an operation of the table as a whole.  I am not quite sure what an operation on all rows should be -- perhaps both, perhaps it depends on the result.

In Python, the usual term for 'record-level' would be 'element-wise'.  For Python builtins, bool operates on collections: `bool([0, 1, 0, 3])` = True.  For numpy arrays, bool operates (at least usually) on elements: `bool([0, 1, 0, 2]) = [False, True, False, True].  Also compare [1,2,3]*2 = [1,2,3,1,2,3] versus [1,2,3]*2 = [2,4,6].

I hope this helps.  See if it makes sense in context.