# Does anyone know the difference between “table-level” operations and “record-level” operations

Tags: python, django

From [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/):

> Managers are accessible only via model classes, rather than from model instances, to enforce a separation between “table-level” operations and “record-level” operations.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187032/what-is-the-difference-between-table-level-operation-and-record-level-operation

Answer (score 0):

table-level operations may affect more than one record or row, like `select` or an `update` with many rows.

row-level operations affect only one row, like `delete` or `update` of a single record.

Comment: I changed the wording of my answer.

Comment: In the case of Djangos ORM, it makes sense to separate them like this so you now which ones semantically belong to an instance and which operations belong to the manager.

Comment: i asked that question as I wondered why when I write any query why 
there are no parentheses for example modelname().objects.all() as I make an instance from the model class then I call objects attribute.